# How preserve line breaks and escape slashes using jQuery .html()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am pulling text from a `MySQL` database using `jQuery AJAX` and I am trying to find a way I can preserve the line breaks and remove the slashes to prevent the text being displayed as below

> Manufacturer\'s Warranty replacement ordered by Tracey. Order was sent
>   to email@address.com - 14-04-2016 11:05:20pm\nFault reported: dead
>   final

I am using `.html()` to output the text

```
$parent.find(".more_details_desc").html(notes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unescape()` function. ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape))

```
unescape("Manufacturer\'s Warranty replacement ordered by Tracey. Order was sent to email@address.com - 14-04-2016 11:05:20pm\nFault reported: dead final")
```

Result:

```
"Manufacturer's Warranty replacement ordered by Tracey. Order was sent to email@address.com - 14-04-2016 11:05:20pm
Fault reported: dead final"
```

You should be able to then write `$parent.find(".more_details_desc").html(unescape(notes));`

Comment: note that this answer is right, but i think it has a little mistake, in the last line it uses  escape(notes)   instead of   unescape(notes), like my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$parent.find(".more_details_desc").html(unescape(notes));
```